# How to convert a http to a https URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, url, https

Using Swift4 - how do you convert `http://www.myWebsite.com` to `https://www.myWebsite.com` ?

Please pay attention to the small detail: http  vs. http**s**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you are working with strings, you can use simple text replacement:

```
let http = "http://some.com/example.html"
let https = "https" + http.dropFirst(4)
```

Or you can use `URLComponents`:

```
let http = "http://some.com/example.html"
var comps = URLComponents(string: http)!
comps.scheme = "https"
let https = comps.string!
```

If you have a `URL`, you can still use `URLComponents`:

```
let http = URL(string: "http://some.com/example.html")!
var comps = URLComponents(url: http, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
comps.scheme = "https"
let https = comps.url!
```

**Note**: I've used `!` in several places to show the core solution. Provide proper optional and error handling as needed for proper code.

Comment: Thank you, maddy - looks simple enough.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that best solve your questions. I noticed you haven't accepted a single answer to one of your questions in quite some time. You really should go back and accept answers where appropriate.

Comment: I accepted now until about 20 questions back. The reason why I hesitate with accepting is that more answers are coming in (that might even be better than the ones already received - and by accepting I feel this puts a stopp to more answers....)

Comment: It's fine to wait a day or two but you hadn't accepted anything in a year. That's a bit excessive. And in this case your question has been closed so it can't get any more answers.

Comment: if the original url is `x.com` the final result will be `https:x.com` which is not a valid URL